# How to define variance weighted parameter for multioutput regression problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using RandomForestRegressor to build my regression model, there are ~30 columns in input and 5 columns in output in that model, and I do a train test split for measuring the model performance.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rfreg = RandomForestRegressor()
rfreg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predict = rfreg.predict(X_test)
rfreg.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

However, an error pops up which told me to define the value metrics.r2_score manually, otherwise, it uses 'uniform_average' for the model

```
C:\Users\X\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:420: FutureWarning: The default value of multioutput (not exposed in score method) will change from 'variance_weighted' to 'uniform_average' in 0.23 to keep consistent with 'metrics.r2_score'. To specify the default value manually and avoid the warning, please either call 'metrics.r2_score' directly or make a custom scorer with 'metrics.make_scorer' (the built-in scorer 'r2' uses multioutput='uniform_average').
  "multioutput='uniform_average').", FutureWarning)
```

I checked the manual and source code for RandomForestRegressor.score function available on sklearn website: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score

```
        from .metrics import r2_score
        from .metrics._regression import _check_reg_targets
        y_pred = self.predict(X)
        # XXX: Remove the check in 0.23
        y_type, _, _, _ = _check_reg_targets(y, y_pred, None)
        if y_type == 'continuous-multioutput':
            warnings.warn("The default value of multioutput (not exposed in "
                          "score method) will change from 'variance_weighted' "
                          "to 'uniform_average' in 0.23 to keep consistent "
                          "with 'metrics.r2_score'. To specify the default "
                          "value manually and avoid the warning, please "
                          "either call 'metrics.r2_score' directly or make a "
                          "custom scorer with 'metrics.make_scorer' (the "
                          "built-in scorer 'r2' uses "
                          "multioutput='uniform_average').", FutureWarning)
        return r2_score(y, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight,
                        multioutput='variance_weighted')
```

But I'm still not sure how to define 
`multioutput='variance_weighted'`
in 
`rfreg.score(X_test, Y_test)` in my case.

Furthermore, I wonder if the model performance will improve if I change the values from `multioutput='uniform_weighted'` to `multioutput='variance_weighted'`? Also, how to determine the weighting for each output columns? Thanks.